# How to show DOM but disable click functionality in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to show checkox and label to customers but disable click functionality in a certain scenario. Here is my html code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="billing-address-same-as-shipping"
       data-bind="checked: isAddressSameAsShipping, disable: disableBillingSameAsShipping(), click: useShippingAddress, attr: {id: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"/>
<label data-bind="disable: disableBillingSameAsShipping(), attr: {for: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"><span
        data-bind="i18n: 'My billing and shipping address are the same'"></span></label>
```

Here is a function which returns true or false:

```
disableBillingSameAsShipping: function () {
    if(quote.shippingAddress().city == undefined) {
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If `disableBillingSameAsShipping` function returns `true` input box and label in not visible on the page.

How I can customize it such that when return value is true, checkbox and label should be visble on the page but click/select functionality should be disabled for both?

Comment: That doesn't make sense... is there any error in the console?

Comment: I do not see any error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `disable` binding on the actual `<input>`, not on it's label.

```js
const checked = ko.observable(false);
const disable = ko.observable(true);

ko.applyBindings({ checked, disable });
```

```css
input[disabled] { opacity: .5 };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: disable">
    Checkbox below is disabled
  </label>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checked, disable: disable">
    This checkbox is <span data-bind="text: disable() ? 'disabled' : 'enabled'"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No data-bind is required in the `label` tag. Simply, do the following for `input` tag (use `enable` binding):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="billing-address-same-as-shipping" data-bind="checked: isAddressSameAsShipping, enable: !disableBillingSameAsShipping(), click: useShippingAddress, attr: {id: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"/>
```

And this should be the `label` binding:

```
<label data-bind="attr: {for: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"><span data-bind="i18n: 'My billing and shipping address are the same'"></span></label>
```